# Using Rmarkdown with CSS from CDN

Tags: css, r, twitter-bootstrap, knitr, r-markdown

I want to create a Rmarkdown using the Bootstrap CSS from CDN (http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css).

I'm trying to do this, but it didn't works...

This is what I tried (I tried without using NULL, and without " " too, but I had the same error)

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: NULL
    highlight: NULL
    css: "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"

---
```

The resulting error is:

```
"E:/Program Files/R/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS teste.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output teste.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\diego\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --css "http:\\maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\bootstrap\3.3.6\css\bootstrap.min.css" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --no-highlight 
output file: teste.knit.md

pandoc.exe: Could not fetch http:\\maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\bootstrap\3.3.6\css\bootstrap.min.css
InvalidUrlException "http:%5C%5Cmaxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com%5Cbootstrap%5C3.3.6%5Ccss%5Cbootstrap.min.css" "URL must be absolute"
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
Besides that: Warning message:
command execution '"E:/Program Files/R/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS teste.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output teste.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\diego\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --css "http:\\maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\bootstrap\3.3.6\css\bootstrap.min.css" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --no-highlight' teve status 67 
Execution interrupted
```

There is some way to refer to a online CSS with a absolute path?

Thanks,

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. What package versions are you using?

Comment: @user5219763 I think the OP was using Windows, and forward slashes were replaced by backslashes on Windows in rmarkdown. The `css` argument is supposed to take local files; perhaps it makes sense to file a feature request to the rmarkdown repo on Github to support non-local resources as well.

Comment: @Yihui I saw on the rmarkdown documentation that Mathjax support external url, so I supposed that `css` would work as well. But maybe you are right. I will put a feature request on Github.

Comment: @user5219763 I'm using: `R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) / rmarkdown: 0.9.5 / knitr 1.12.3 / Windows 7 64 bits` . Your system is not Windows? Maybe the error occur because the slashs like @Yihui said. What do you think?

Comment: The issue on Rmarkdown Github:
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/631

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Rmarkdown Github member @jjallaire:

External URLs for the css option aren't supported, however you could do this instead:

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: NULL
    highlight: NULL
---

<style type="text/css">
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css");
</style>
—
```

EDITED:
Another solution I found on Rmarkdown page:

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
    highlight: tango
---
```

The the flatly come from Bootstrap and have the bootstrap styles.